# Given $P(C)$ and $P(A\mid C)$, what is $P(C\mid A)$?

Tags: probability

I am wondering if there's a way to find the solution if we know:

$P(C) = 0.01$

$P(A\mid C) = 0.7$

what is $P(C\mid A)$?

I think we need to know $P(A)$ to answer this question right? There is no other way around it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
\Pr(A) & = \Pr(A\mid C)\Pr(C) + \Pr(A\mid \text{not }C)\Pr(\text{not }C) \\[10pt]
& = \Pr(A\mid C)\Pr(C) + \Pr(A\mid \text{not }C)\Big( 1 - \Pr(C) \Big) \\[10pt]
& = (0.7)(0.01) + \Pr(A\mid\text{not }C)( 1 - 0.01) \\[10pt]
& = 0.007 + 0.99\Pr(A \mid \text{not } C) \\[10pt]
& \in [0.007,\, 0.997]
\end{align}
Since the probability of $C$ is so small, this range at the end is very wide.

So
$$
1 \ge \frac{0.007}{\Pr(A)} \ge \frac{0.007}{0.997} \approx 0.007021063\ldots
$$

Comment: Thank you for providing an alternative/approximate solution. Could you please elaborate on how you deduced the upper bound of 0.997 from "0.99 * Pr(A|not C)"? You said because "probability of 'C' is so small, the range at the end is very wide". Could you elaborate more on that for someone like me who does not have advanced level knowledge of probability? Thank you!

Comment: @user1330974 : I looked at the extreme case in which $\Pr(A\mid\text{not }C)=1$.  In that case, $0.007 + 0.99\Pr(A\mid\text{not }C)$ comes to $0.997$. $\qquad$

Answer (score 3):

Considering the given data, without knowing anything more, one may just write
$$
P_A(C)=\frac{P(A \cap C)}{P(A)}=\frac{P(A \cap C)}{P(C)}\cdot \frac{P(C)}{P(A)}=0.7\frac{0.01}{P(A)}=\color{red}{\frac{0.007}{P(A)}}.
$$

Comment: Yes, that's what I could think of as well. I'll accept your answer after waiting for a day and if no one can provide a better solution. :) Thank you!

Comment: @user1330974 You are welcome.